# File not Found Exception

Tags: apache-nifi

I want  to get flowfile  in which is xml components and  update  one  of the tagvalue  i make it  inside custom  nifi  processor code , I  have  code  like this:

```
  flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile,"filename",file.getName() + ".xml");
                InputSource inputSource = new InputSource((InputStream) flowFile);
                DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(inputSource);
                XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
                NodeList myNodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("//runAs/text()")
                        .evaluate(flowFile, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                myNodeList.item(0).setNodeValue("false");
```

but it  trows  File  not Found Exception exception,  what  should i  change to make  this code  work p.s i can't use path for flowfile

Answer (score 3):

the nifi flow file is not an InputStream.

so the code `(InputStream) flowFile` is wrong

if you want to get content of the flow file as an input stream you can use `session.read` method like this:

```
InputStream ffStream = session.read(flowFile);
...do something with stream
ffStream.close();
```

Comment: you did it in your code except the way how to get stream from flow file. (i mentioned in answer)

Comment: I can't close  fstream after  all this  operations i mean : DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(inputSource);
                XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
                NodeList myNodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("//runAs/text()")
                        .evaluate(flowFile, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                myNodeList.item(0).setNodeValue("false");

Comment: you can close stream just after stream was parsed: `builder.parse(inputSource)`

Comment: I guess  in this  case i  can't  update  my nodesetValue i mean this  : NodeList myNodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("//runAs/text()")
                        .evaluate(flowFile, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                myNodeList.item(0).setNodeValue("false");

Comment: after parsing you will have a copy of your flow file in memory but represented as xml. by calling `setNodeValue` you make changes in memory-based xml object.  if you want to save changed xml into flow file - you have to do `session.write(flowFile,...)`

Comment: should  i  write xmlDocument  data .getBytes()  for  writeing  in flowfile?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155931/discussion-between-sally-tkhilaishvili-and-daggett).